# Best way of formatting a given paragraph (or set of paragraphs) in ConTeXt

Tags: formatting, context

Altough I have read the documentation, I have not find a definitive answer for this, so I hope somebody has a better understanding that I have.

I want to make a paragraph (or set of) stand out from others, for example, let's imagine in a novel:

- You center a text which your character is reading
- You want to write some block of text in intalics and aligned to the right, for example the header of a letter your character is reading.

This paragraph is inside a chapter or scene, it is not a section of the text by itself, so since I don't know how to effectively get this effect, before making any mistake, I prefer to ask.

Right now I consider these posibilities:

- Text block
- Frame
- New command which typesets exactly what I want
- Combining several of the above

Comment: I think the reason you haven't found a definitive answer is because it's a matter of taste/external restrictions potentially imposed on you.

Comment: I find difficult to get the 'flavour' of doing things in ConTeXt, coming from a LaTeX background. In LaTeX I would have solved this by defining a new environment, for example.

I am agraif of taking a course of action only to discover that it is fundamentally flawed by some mistake I have not seen because of my inexperience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many different ways to change the layout of a certain text block.

To change the color of a paragraph you can enclose it in a `\startcolor` environment.

```
\starttext

\input ward

\startcolor[orange]
\input ward
\stopcolor

\stoptext
```

To choose a special font for a paragraph you can use the `\startfont` environment which takes the same argument as the `\definedfont` command.

```
\starttext

\input ward

\startfont[SansBold]
\input ward
\stopfont

\stoptext
```

With the `\startstyle` environment you can set the style and color for a paragraph. You can either set both values as argument to the `\startcolor` command or create a named set with the `\definestyle` command which name is used as argument for the `\startstyle` command.

```
\definestyle[important][color=blue,style=italic]

\starttext

\input ward

\startstyle[important]
\input ward
\stopstyle

\input ward

\startstyle[color=red,style=bold]
\input ward
\stopstyle

\stoptext
```

The alignment of one or more paragraphs can be changed with the `\startalignment` environment which takes the same argument as the `\setupalign` command.

```
\starttext

\input ward

\startalignment[middle]
\input ward
\stopalignment

\stoptext
```

The disadvantage of the examples above is that there is no separation between markup and content but this can be achieved with the following two solution.

The first method is the `\startparagraph` environment which allows you to set the style and color for a paragraph. Additional settings can be added with the `setups` key which can be used to change the alignment of the content.

```
\startsetups[paragraph:important]
  \setupalign[middle]
\stopsetups

\defineparagraph
  [important]
  [color=green
   style=italic,
   setups=paragraph:important]

\starttext

\input ward

\startparagraph[important]
\input ward
\stopparagraph

\stoptext
```

The second method is to use the `\definestartstop` command to create your own environment where you set the style and color of the content.  With the `commands` key (the use of a `\startsetups` environment isn’t necessary) you can add additional setups. When you use this method you have to ensure the paragraph ends before the `stop` command to ensure the alignment takes effect.

```
\startsetups[startstop:important]
  \setupalign[middle]
\stopsetups

\definestartstop
  [important]
  [color=green
   style=italic,
  %before={\startnarrower[2*middle]},
  %after=\stopnarrower,
   commands=\directsetup{startstop:important}]

\starttext

\input ward

\startimportant
\input ward\par
\stopimportant

\stoptext
```

Comment: This has been a very useful answer, thank you! My question had no definite answer, but this one has a well explained exposition of several choices which has helped much.